# Equivalence between category of $R$-modules and $S$-modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, category-theory, modules

Is it true that by equivalence between category of $R$-modules and $S$-modules we conclude that $R$ and $S$ are isomorphic?($R$ and $S$ are unital rings.)

Comment: One would usually only consider equivalences, as isomorphisms of categories are mostly nonexistent in nature — and then the rings need not be isomorphic; the keyword for this is «Morita equivalence».

Comment: @ Mariano:Thanks for your comment. i edited this.

Comment: "as isomorphisms of categories are mostly nonexistent in nature" is wrong, although many people claim this.

Comment: @2000 If you additionally require that both $R$ and $S$ are commutative, then the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: @  rschwieb: thanks. because of $End(id_M) \cong Z(R)$!

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, of course it is wrong. There do exist isomorphisms. Can you give an example relevant to this question?

Comment: If $R,S$ are isomorphic rings, then $\mathsf{Mod}_R$ and $\mathsf{Mod}_S$ are isomorphic. This is boring, of course, but nevertheless this statement is used all the time "secretly" when we "translate" module theory along isomorphic rings. A very interesting isomorphism of categories is the one between the finite topological spaces and the finite preorders (but of course this does not belong to module theory).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $A$ is any ring, then $A$ and $M_n(A)$ have equivalent categories of modules, and usually $A$ and $M_n(A)$ are not isomorphic.

This is the simplest example of a Morita equivalence.

Comment: what is $M_n(A)$?

Comment: The ring of $n×n$ matrixes with entries in $A$.